# how to display the post user created with {% if user.is_authenticated == post.author %}?

Tags: python, django

this is what I'm trying to do: users can create community(or post) and I want in some where in my template, to display the community the user created. 
So in models.py I have

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

and in my views.py

```
@login_required
def add_category(request):
    if not request.user.is_superuser and Category.objects.filter(author=request.user).exists():
        return render(request,'main/category_already_exists.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category(author=request.user)
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=category)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('category', category_name_url=category.name)

    else:
        form = CategoryForm()
    context = {
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, 'main/add_category.html',context)
```

and this is my simplified category view

```
def category(request, category_name_url):
    category_name = decode_url(category_name_url)


                category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name)

    context = {

                "category":category,



        }
    return render(request, "main/category.html", context)
```

so I tried this in my template with thinking it would work for sure

```
{% if user.is_authenticated == category.author %}
             <h1>hello</h1>
            {% else %}
              <h1>nah</h1>
            {% endif %}
```

but when it should print hello it prints nah, what's my fault here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% if user.is_authenticated == category.author %}
```

is not a valid check. `user.is_authenticated` returns a boolean (`True`/`False`), and `category.author` is a `user` object. You are checking for equality incorrectly.

Try this instead:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user == category.author %}
```

since `category.author` is a `User` instance

Comment: I approached this situation wrong, I was trying to display the category user created in every page but with the way I did it's only displaying in the category page that user created, can you please help me how I should do this...

Comment: Do you mean you want to send a list of all categories created by the current user on every page ? If so, you might want to set a queryset in a template context processor - and cache the queryset..

Comment: yes that's what I'm trying to do, ok I think I can give that a shot thank you

Comment: hmm then I should do that in user model right?like category = models.foreignkey('category') ?

Comment: No, your query set would be something you set in the view. Actually, you need to read up on template context processors https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/

Comment: hmm....can you help me with this one...I'm still a beginner I just finished a few tutorials

Comment: Its too hard for me to help in comments, and it is really late in the night for me.. sorry.. If this can wait, i can take it up in the AM.. But if you want a quicker response, please create a new question - i am sure someone can give you a good solution.